# one to many returns only one result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have have 3 tables

table1:
product_id
name
description

table2:
category_id
name
description

table3:
product_id
category_id

Im trying to create a query that selects a table with the following data: product_name,product_description,product_category

The thing is each row should contain more than one product_category but the query only returns one.

Here's the query, if you could kindly let me know what part is incorrect

```
SELECT table1.name AS product_name,
       table1.description AS product_description,
       table2.name AS product_category
FROM table1 INNER JOIN
     table3
     ON table3.product_id = table1.product_id INNER JOIN
     table2
     ON table2.category_id = table3.category_id;
```

The result i get is :

```
product_name  -   product_description  -  product_category
NAME 1    -      Description 1     -     Category 1
NAME 2    -      Description 2     -     Category 2
```

Im aiming for something like this:

```
product_name  -   product_description  -  product_category
NAME 1    -      Description 1         -     Category 1
                                             Category 2
                                             Category 5

NAME 2    -      Description 2     -     Category 7
                                         Category 2
                                         Category 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer all credit goes to @Gordon Linoff as all i needed to do was to add the product_id to the grouping

Here's the query:

```
SELECT t1.name AS product_name,
t1.description AS product_description,
GROUP_CONCAT(t2.name) AS product_category
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN
table3 t3
ON t3.product_id = t1.product_id INNER JOIN
table2 t2
ON t2.category_id = t3.category_id
GROUP BY t1.product_id, t1.name, t1.description;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want multiple product categories in one row, then think "aggregation":

```
SELECT t1.name AS product_name,
       t1.description AS product_description,
       GROUP_CONCAT(t2.name) AS product_category
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN
     table3 t3
     ON t3.product_id = t1.product_id INNER JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t2.category_id = t3.category_id
GROUP BY t1.name, t1.description;
```

Comment: Thank you very much i think this is getting me very close, however its still returning with one table3.name only while it should return more as stated in the description

Comment: @jukerok . . . Your comment makes no sense.  `table3` doesn't have a column called `name`.

Comment: My bad i mean table2.name

Comment: @jukerok . . . The number of `table2.name` values returns is based on what is in `table3`.  Nothing in the query (other than the inner joins) is filtering out values.